# Parse server error: Code=3840

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have an app with a Parse server hosted by Sashido.
I tried to use the following cloud function, in order to get the top percentage of a user:

```
Parse.Cloud.define(Constants.kParseFunctionGetPercentageOfUser, function(request, response) {
  var userRankQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  userRankQuery.greaterThan(Constants.kClassUserKeyOverallLikes, request.params.likes);
  userRankQuery.count().then(function(count) {
    var rank = count + 1;
    console.info(Constants.kParseFunctionGetPercentageOfUser + " found rank: " + rank);
    var allUsersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    console.info("allUsersQuery: " + JSON.stringify(allUsersQuery));
    return allUsersQuery.count();
  }).then(function(nrAllUsers) {
    console.info("response.success: rank = " + rank + ", nrAllUsers = " + nrAllUsers);
    response.success(rank*100.0/nrAllUsers);
  }, function(error){
    console.info("response.error: " + error);
    response.error(Constants.kParseFunctionGetPercentageOfUser + " query failed: " + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
});
```

I hope this function is syntactically correct.

However, the Parse server logs only the 2 statements

```
console.info(Constants.kParseFunctionGetPercentageOfUser + " found rank: " + rank);
```

and

```
console.info("allUsersQuery: " + JSON.stringify(allUsersQuery));
```

and then seems to hang. At least, it takes maybe 30 sec, and after some network timeout notifications, I get the error:

```
errorError Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 
"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
```

I thus imagine that the Parse sever hangs, and after the timeout, my app gets this error.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @ronw: Sorry, not yet. I contacted Sashido support  (Ticket ID: 84916893) 10 days ago, but I did not yet get any answer...